# Symfony 2.8 to 3.0 - Authentication fails

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony3.x

I am trying to upgrade and my authentication is failing. I haven't changed anything in my security.yml files and have removed all extra security bundles. I'm unclear what could be going on or even how to debug this issue. The logs dont show me much.

```html
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~

        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            default_target_path: splash
            success_handler: authentication.success.listener

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: homepage

    encoders:
      AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: md5
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false

    providers:
        user_db1:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User
                property: username
```

any direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the "not much" the logs are showing?

Comment: and using md5 isn't recommended at all

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: It just says bad credentials.